# Google Wallet integration in android for Payment

Tags: android, android-pay

I have develop an application that have online payment functionality so i think google wallet is best for it so any one can suggest me how to implement in android code step by step 
i am new in online payment gateways type of application

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use google instant buy for payment through google wallet 
here is link for tutorial

[Google Wallet Integration](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial)